# Solving $L = 4\pi C_x d^2$ for $d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to re-arrange the following equation to solve for $d$:

$$L = 4\pi C_x d^2$$

Thank you.

Comment: Try reading the FAQ before posting (always a good idea in any online community): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117

Comment: I'm confused by the image you linked to. I don't really understand how this is a differential equation? Perhaps you could use the following link: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to produce the equation in latex. You need to take whatever code the box generates and enclose it in dollar signs for it to show up properly.

Comment: As was pointed out in your other question, "make d the subject" will be more understood if you say "solve for d"

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant 'solve for d'. Just trying to get the hang of writing the equation in latex.

Comment: @Dennis Henry: I'm sorry, but how is this (differential-equations)? This is precalculus algebra.

Comment: Apologies Arturo.

Comment: @Dennis Henry: Divide. Take square roots. Get rid of the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arturo said

$$L=4 \pi C_x d^2$$

$$\implies d^2 = \frac{L}{4 \pi C_x}$$

$$\implies d= \pm\sqrt{\frac{L}{4 \pi C_x}}$$

Your equation looks like it is physical, so the negative square root may not be relevant